# How to open a mpp file with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to open and read the information of a `.mpp` file with python but not having much success. I tried with the `olefile` library by doing

```
filename = "my_file.mpp"
with olefile.OleFileIO(filename) as ole:
    print(ole.open())
```

But I print a `NoneType` object. Also tried same thing with other files, like `.doc`, but I get the same results.

How can I see the information that is in the file? What I'm doing wrong? I don't have MS Project in my PC, but I do have MS Word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a typo in the files name

Comment: please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413657/reading-mpp-file-from-python-2-7) site.